# Re-disable extensions for large files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw when I tried to open an 80MB txt file that some features were disabled to prevent crashes or not. I accidentally clicked forcibly reenable extensions but now vscode is extremely laggy when I try to browse the file.

Does anyone know how to re-disable those extensions like tokenization when opening large files again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling this setting:

> `Editor: Large File Optimizations`
> Special handling for large files to disable certain memory-intensive features.